# how to interpret json from web service call

Tags: ios, json

in my iOS app, I successfully received the following json(I think it is json):

```
{
    data =     {
        "current_condition" =         (
                        {
                cloudcover = 16;
                humidity = 59;
                "observation_time" = "09:09 PM";
                precipMM = "0.1";
                pressure = 1010;
                "temp_C" = 10;
                "temp_F" = 49;
                visibility = 10;
                weatherCode = 113;
                weatherDesc =                 (
                                        {
                        value = Clear;
                    }
                );
                weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                        {
                        value = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night.png";
                    }
                );
                winddir16Point = NW;
                winddirDegree = 316;
                windspeedKmph = 47;
                windspeedMiles = 29;
            }
        );
        request =         (
                        {
                query = "Lat 32.35 and Lon 141.43";
                type = LatLon;
            }
        );
        weather =         (
                        {
                date = "2013-01-15";
                precipMM = "1.8";
                tempMaxC = 12;
                tempMaxF = 53;
                tempMinC = 10;
                tempMinF = 50;
                weatherCode = 119;
                weatherDesc =                 (
                                        {
                        value = Cloudy;
                    }
                );
                weatherIconUrl =                 (
                                        {
                        value = "http://www.worldweatheronline.com/images/wsymbols01_png_64/wsymbol_0003_white_cloud.png";
                    }
                );
                winddir16Point = NNW;
                winddirDegree = 348;
                winddirection = NNW;
                windspeedKmph = 66;
                windspeedMiles = 41;
            },
                        {
                date = "2013-01-16";
                precipMM = "0.6";
                tempMaxC = 13;
                tempMaxF = 56;
                tempMinC = 11;
                tempMinF = 51;
                weatherCode = 113;
                weatherDesc =                 (
                                        {
                        value = Sunny;
                    }
                );
```

what is data considered here? is it the root of the json object? what is current condition ? I guess i need an explanation of how to interpret this json, so I can display it in a tableview. I tried to go over this json [tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-json--active-8817), but the json in there is completely different! It uses ":" to separate key value ,but this json does not have it. I am totally confused

Comment: So where did that text come from?

Comment: would please paste here the url from where you find this

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that looks like JSON. Take a look at the `NSJSONSerialization` class. It's dirt-simple to use. You pass the `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` method an `NSData` object containing the JSON you want to read, and it hands back a Foundation Class object that represents the JSON data "object graph". In your case it looks like the top-level object is a dictionary, so you should get back an NSDictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It look like json. You can manipulate data by this way.

```
id jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
if ([greeting isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    //manipulate dictionary
}else if ([greeting isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
//manipulate array
}else{
//manipulate other
}
```